# A way to link 2 steps to the same step definition in behave python

Tags: python, cucumber, bdd, python-behave

user load the shared session
user load the shared session SessionX

i need these tow to be linked to the same step definition

Note that "SessionX" is not fixed

@step("user load the shared session{session_name}")
def load_session(context, action, session_name)

What is the regex expression to do this in python ?

i tried @step("user load the shared session{?session_name?}")
and @step("user load the shared session{?:session_name}")

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.